# Missing vertical line at the end of the first line

Tags: tables

I am new to Latex and I have tried to create a table but it seems not to work correctly - the vertical line is missed. Here is the code:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{|r|l|c|c|c|}
    \hline &&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bf Results}\\
    \hline\bf Nr.& \bf Features&\bf Strict &\bf Outer &\bf Inner\\ \hline
    1&Morphological F.&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    2&1 + Bla &100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    3&2 + Blabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    4&3 + blablabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    5&4 + blablablabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \caption{\label{font-table} Results. }
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}
```

Here is the output that I become :(

[image]

I think that something is wrong with the 5 line, but it seems I have tried everything :(

Comment: Have you tried to write your 5th line like this: 
`\hline &&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bf Results}\\`

Comment: unrelated to the lines you just want `\centering` not `\centering\begin{center}` and also `\bfseries` not `\bf`

Comment: Use `\hline &&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries Results}\\`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `|` in your `\multicolumn` (first row). Delete the `center` environment: it only adds spurious vertical spacing:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}{|r|l|c|c|c|}
    \hline &&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bf Results}\\
    \hline\bf Nr.& \bf Features&\bf Strict &\bf Outer &\bf Inner\\ \hline
    1&Morphological F.&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    2&1 + Bla &100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    3&2 + Blabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    4&3 + blablabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    5&4 + blablablabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
  \caption{\label{font-table} Results. }
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look, I've add something and worked for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{|r|l|c|c|c|}
    \hline &&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bf Results}\\
    \hline\bf Nr.& \bf Features&\bf Strict &\bf Outer &\bf Inner\\ \hline
    1&Morphological F.&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    2&1 + Bla &100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    3&2 + Blabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    4&3 + blablabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    5&4 + blablablabla&100.00&100.00&100.00\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \caption{\label{font-table} Results. }
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed `\hline &&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bf Results}\\` for `\hline &&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bf Results}\\`

Comment: \multicolumn{3}{`c|`} is enough. You were posting your answer while I finished mine. Sorry for the (almost) duplicate. If you want, I withdraw my answer.

Comment: I saw it with your answer, just `{c|}` is enough. Is mandatory to erase one of the answers?

Comment: I guess not. It's just they're almost the same (anyway, there weren't many choices to answer…).