# tabular missing vertical line on right

Tags: tables, multicolumn

So this code is causing an issue where the bar to the right of the Sigma is interrupted. How can I overcome this?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}
    \hline
    $\delta$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Sigma$} \\
    States & a & b\\
    \hline
    $q_0$ & $\{q_0\}$ & $\{q_1\}$ \\
    $q_1$ & $\{q_1\}$ & $\{q_2\}$ \\
    $q_2$ & $\{q_1\}$ & $\{q_2\}$ \\
    \hline
    
\end{tabular}
```

yields

[image: picture demonstrating a missing portion of the right side vertical bar]

Comment: look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194214/missing-vertical-line-at-the-end-of-the-first-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use multicolumn inside the tabular environment, you need to specify the alignment of the column(s) you want to merge. In other words, you need to include the specifier `c|` within the curly braces of the `\multicolumn` command to indicate that you want a vertical line to appear between the merged columns.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}
\hline
$\delta$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\Sigma$} \\
States & a & b\\
\hline
$q_0$ & $\{q_0\}$ & $\{q_1\}$ \\
$q_1$ & $\{q_1\}$ & $\{q_2\}$ \\
$q_2$ & $\{q_1\}$ & $\{q_2\}$ \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
```